# Sklearn : Get last split from timeSeriesSplit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

So I am using the [timeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) from sklearn to split my data like this,

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
```

Now I know in order to get the split indices we have to iterate over `tscv.split(X)`. My question here is, is it possible to get directly to the last split, without iterating over the splits. The object returned by the function is not exactly a list, so I am not sure how to do this ? I need the last split only, since my data is large and no. of splits is also large.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

***Split*** method in `TimeSeriesSplit` **generates split of indices**. *In order to get to specific split you need to iterate to it*. *It is made to iterate over all possible splits for time-series cross validation*.

If size of the test data in the cv split equals `s`. Then, no matter how many splits you make, last split sets `train_data` = `all data except last s data point` and `test_data as last s data points`. So, if you want the last split directly: Slice your data. For eg. if you data is a numpy array `X`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [0, 4], [1, 2], [2, 4] ,[1, 2], [7, 4], [8, 2], [5, 4]])

n_splits = 2                                       # select no of splits required
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = n_splits)

n_samples = X.shape[0]                             # this is how test_size (s)
s = n_samples//(n_splits + 1)                      # is evaluated internally              

X_train_last, X_test_last = X[ :-s], X[-s: ]       # s=2 for this split

X_train_last
# array([[1, 2],
#        [0, 4],
#        [1, 2],
#        [2, 4],
#        [1, 2],
#        [7, 4]])

X_test_last
# array([[8, 2],
#       [5, 4]])
```

*Also, if you have set the "max_train_size", while splitting. Then you need to take care of that too while slicing. Refer TimeSeriesSplit [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) for details.*

Comment: In the above sample, I have trouble understanding what value is added by using the TimeSeriesSplit-function. All the work is done in the three lines following. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Anne It was answered taking into consideration the user is using both the `TimeSeriesSplit` method and the last slice, somewhere in their analysis. If you are not going to iterate over all splits then its of no use to you.